# Some misconception with linked list implementation

Tags: c, linked-list

It seems that I have a major misconception as to how I can implement a linked list in C. As far as I can understand (and this code is as simplified as can be!), this should work, but instead returns a segmentation fault. Also worth noting that if I comment out everything below `MARKER`, it seems to be working, but there is probably an underlying issue that makes it all faulty.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


typedef struct node
{
    int val;
    struct node *next;
} node;


int main (void)
{
    node *pode;
    node *nx, *vx, *sx;

    pode = (node *) malloc(1 * sizeof(node));
    pode->val = 12;

    pode = (node *) realloc(pode, 2 * sizeof(node));
    pode->next = (pode + 1);
    (pode + 1)->val = 66;

    pode = (node *) realloc(pode, 3 * sizeof(node));
    pode->next = (pode + 2);
    (pode + 2)->val = 33;

    pode = (node *) realloc(pode, 4 * sizeof(node));
    pode->next = (pode + 3);
    (pode + 3)->val = 44;


    printf("%d\n", pode->val);

    nx = pode->next;
    printf("%d\n", nx->val);

    // MARKER
    vx = nx->next;
    printf("%d\n", vx->val);

    sx = nx->next;
    printf("%d\n", sx->val);

    return 0;
}
```

Where's the boo-boo?

Comment: If `realloc` decides to move the memory block, then `pode->next` points to the old memory block which was freed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, your first mistake is using `realloc()`. That's easy to get burned with because it might or might not move the node, causing any pointers to it to become dangerous dangling pointers.

Linked lists are all about linking the nodes together with pointers, so there's no reason to reallocate one node into a larger node, and that defeats the ability to splice the list by changing pointers. Generally, you'd allocate each node separately. (In some cases a program might deallocate list nodes by putting them into a "free" list for very fast deallocation and later reallocation.)

Your second mistake is forgetting to set each node's `next` pointer as soon as you allocate the node. Don't rely on the allocator to clear it.

Even if the code did set all the `next` pointers correctly, `realloc()` may move the node, breaking all those pointers.

Finally, if you step through the running program in a debugger (e.g. CLion), you'll be able to see where you have dangling pointers.

Comment: "realloc is slow". Compared to what? Citation or evidence?

Comment: @rici Fair question. Compared to removing a node from a free list, very slow. Compared to malloc(), it has to try to grow the node in place, else malloc, memcpy, and free, and that's not to mention the O(N^2) behavior in the question, which allocates each additional node by expanding/copying all the previous nodes.

Comment: Well, you're definitely right about dangling pointers but if you are always going to allocate contiguous storage, you don't need pointers. So the data structure can be smaller and its also cache friendlier. Realloc'ing a vector smaller is usually a no-op and often realloc'ing it bigger is also little work if the allocation is big enough. Some realloc implementations will overallocate, so OPs strategy is not necessarily quadratic (although I would only recommend it for non-production code.)

Comment: @rici Yes. Much could be taught about how to implement vectors, but the question was how to fix the linked list implementation.

Comment: I agree. I only objected to the realloc is slow comment, which seemed totally out of place to me. OP shouldn't use it because it won't work (dangling pointers); its speed is irrelevant.

Comment: @rici Agreed. I removed the "`realloc()` is slow" sentence since speed is irrelevant to the problem at hand. Allocation strategy is relevant to understanding linked lists vs. vectors, but that's a larger discussion.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 issues here. Why does my code crash? Is this the 'right', 'idiomatic' way to do linked lists?

Second one first. No it is not. The normal way is to malloc each node separately and link the together. What you are really building is a resizable array. you need

```
    node *pode; // the head
    node *n, *prev;

    pode = (node *) malloc(sizeof(node));
    pode->val = 12;

    n = (node *) malloc(sizeof(node));
    pode->next = n;
    n->val = 66;
    prev = n;
    n = (node *) malloc(sizeof(node));
    prev->next = n;
   n->val = 33;
    prev = n;
    n = (node *) malloc(sizeof(node));
    prev->next = n;
    n->val = 44;
etc.
```

to find out why your code crashes run it under a debugger